# How to Join three tables with multiple values rows returned on the other two

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Say for example.

I have three separate tables:

1. `course` Table which has CourseId, StudentIds etc
2. `student` which of course contains student data and StudentName
3. `score` table

I only want one column from each table and fuse them into one.

```
CourseId        StudentName            Scores
----------      -------------          ----------
1               Gashio                 10
1               Gashio                 20
1               Lee                    35
1               Lee                    40
1               Edith                  5
2               Lana                   3
2               Reisha                 50
```

For every Course there's multiple students, and for every Scores there's multiple scores they get from the course for a month.

I wanted something like this as a result:

```
CourseId        StudentName           Scores
---------       -------------         -------------
1               Gashio                10|20 
1               Lee                   35|40
1               Edith                 5
2               Lana                  3
2               Reisha                50
```

Since the scores return multiple values, I wanted it to become one column separated by a delimeter.

I'm not sure if this is where I should be using STRING_AGG?

Comment: google-cloud-spanner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `STRING_AGG` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT course.CourseId, 
       student.StudentName, 
       STRING_AGG(Scores, ,'|') AS Scores
  FROM course INNER JOIN
       student ON student.StudentId  = course.StudentId INNER JOIN
       score ON score.studentId = student.StudentId
 GROUP BY cource.CourseId, 
          student.StudentName
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear but the studentName Column is in the table Student_table while the scores are in a separate Table from Course_Table

Comment: then, join the table and then use group by and string_agg in your query. Output will result the same just that values will be referred for a particular name in the joined table

Answer (score 0):

use `string_agg()` with delimeter

```
select CourseId,StudentName,string_agg(Scores,'|') as scores
from tablename
group by CourseId,StudentName
```